# How to Add a Vertical Line Above and Below an Element

Tags: html, css

This is my first question on here, so I apologize in advance if I mess this up! I did try looking through previous questions and didn't see exactly what I was looking for.

I'm a web development student and working on a freelance project. The client asked me to do the html and css for the modal ([Picture of Modal](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TxuSY.png)), and I'm not sure how to do the middle part where it says "OR" with the vertical lines above and below.

I tried adding an empty div and then styling it with border-left, height,  and position absolute, but then the line goes all the way through. l also tried adding two empty divs and adding border-right to the other div and styling it the same way. I think I could maybe make it work like that but seems very hacky. Just wondering if there's a better, easier, more correct way! Any help would be very much appreciated!!

Please let me know if I need to provide more information or if I'm not explaining this well enough.

Thanks!

Comment: Please see the following article on how to add a minimal reproducible example to your question... https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a few different, decent ways of achieving this, but I think [Flexbox layout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Flexible_Box_Layout/Basic_Concepts_of_Flexbox) is a good one. Basically, you make a container for your modal, a div for each 'side pane', then one more for the center separator.

Flex box allows you to split the width or height of a container amongst its children elements. So in this case, you'd have the outer container be `display:flex; flex-direction: row` to stack everything horizontally, then the center separator be `display:flex; flex-direction: column` to center the 'or' disc vertically.

This is nice because it allows the layout to adapt to different amounts of content in each side pane - you don't need to fine-tune the positioning, centering or widths and heights to the content so much.

```css
.container {
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 90%;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

/* Each side of the modal. flex: 1 means they will take priority over the separator - they'll get as much of the width as possible, while the separator gets only what it needs */
.container .pane {
  border: 1px solid green;
  flex: 1;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* This is the box that holds the disc and the vertical line */
.container .separator {
  padding: 1rem;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

/* The vertical line is added with the ::after pseudo element - it sits under the disc, and is absolutely positioned to the top/bottom and center */
.container .separator::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 1rem;
  bottom: 1rem;
  left: 50%;
  border-right: 1px solid #CCC;
  z-index: 1;
}

/* This is the 'or' disc itself. Positioned relative and given a higher z-index so it sits on top of the line. */
.container .separator span {       
  padding: 1rem;
  text-align: center;
  width: 2rem;
  height: 2rem;
  line-height: 2rem;
  border-radius: 50%;
  border: 1px solid #CCC;
  background: #FFF;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 2;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="pane">
    <p>Perspiciatis minima qui repudiandae quaerat. Voluptatibus dolores totam ut aut qui doloribus illum. Maxime minus rerum unde voluptas. Aspernatur facilis exercitationem qui aspernatur. Odit qui in aut modi asperiores recusandae sit.</p>
  </div>
  <div class="separator">
    <span>or</span>
  </div>
  <div class="pane">
    <p>Perspiciatis minima qui repudiandae quaerat. Voluptatibus dolores totam ut aut qui doloribus illum.</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Place each side of the UI (left and right) inside a `div` element, set a border to the left on the second element or alternatively set a border to the right on the first element. Then put such `div`s inside a container with `position: relative` and finally, create a third `div` inside the container you just created with `position: absolute`. Set the `top` and `left` CSS properties for this element, and put some `border` on it to create the enclosing circle shape.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Look at the picture]

There will be a div that fits in the red area, and you can add  **border-left** css to make a vertical line. e.g. **border-left: 2px solid lightgray**

Answer (score 0):

Hello and welcome onboard!

The easiest way for beginners would be create a div and use this technique to center it.

```
position: absolute;
left: 50%;
top: 50%;
transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
```

Tips: Make sure the position of parent div is set as relative so it won't go beyond and run away.

```css
div {
  display: flex;
}

div h2 {
  font-size: 15px;
}

#text {
  margin-top: 6px;
}

.body {
  background-color: #000;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.modal {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 80%;
  height: 180px;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-items: stretch;
  position: relative;
}

.column {
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 50%;
  height: auto;
  align-items: flex-start;
  justify-content: space-between;
  padding: 0 30px 15px 30px;
}

.btn {
  font-size: 12px;
  font-weight: 600;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 6px 0 5px 0;
  border-radius: 3px;
  cursor: pointer;
  transition: 0.3s;
}

.sign-up {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid transparent;
}

.sign-up:hover {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border-color: #000
}

.log-in {
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  border: 1px solid #000;
}

.log-in:hover {
  background-color: #000;
  color: #fff;
}

#form {
  margin-top: 0;
}

#reset-password {
  color: #3d3d3d;
  font-size: 12px;
  text-decoration: underline;
  margin: 9px 0;
}

#email {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  margin-bottom: 3px;
  width: 94%;
}

#password {
  padding: 3px 3px;
  margin-top: 3px;
  width: 94%;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}

.middle-line {
  background-color: #3d3d3d;
  width: 1px;
  height: 85%;
}

.circle {
  background-color: #fff;
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  border: 1px solid #3d3d3d;
  border-radius: 50%;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.circle p {
  font-size: 9px;
}
```

```html
<div class="body">
  <div class="modal">
      <div class="column">
        <h2>Create A New Account</h2>
        <p id="text">
          • View order details<br>
          • Track shipping history<br>
          • Faster checkout in future
        </p>
        <button class="btn sign-up">Sign Up For Free </button>
      </div>
      <div class="column">
        <h2>Log In To Your Account</h2>
        <form id="form">
          <input type="email" id="email" placeholder="Email">
          <input type="password" id="password" placeholder="Password">
        </form>
        <a id="reset-password" href=#>Forgot Your Password?</a>
        <button class="btn log-in">Log In </button>
      </div>
      <div class="middle-line center"></div>
      <div class="circle center">
        <p>OR</p>
      </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

There's another easy approach for you is just add a "border-right : 2px solid grey" on the left container. Here in your case the left container containing "Checkout as a new Customer" and then simple position the text "Or" with border-radius : 30px, width: 30px, height: 30px;

This specific properties will work for you. @Sarah F